# How recursion uses stack data structure?

Tags: c++, recursion, lifo

I had read recently that recursion uses system stack for storing return addresses of function calls. So, I just made a random code to understand this LIFO concept in recursion

```
int fun( int x) 
  {  if ( x<6 || x>6 ) 
       { cout<<x; 
          return 0; 
        } 
      else 
       return max(fun(x-1),fun(x+1)); 
    } 
    int main(){ 
     cout<<fun(6); 
     return 0; 
  }
```

I expect output

`570`

Actual output is

`750`

I was assuming function will call in this order-

`fun(6)->fun(5) { it will print 5 then return 0} ->fun(7) { it print 7 then return 0} -> max(0,0) { return 0}`

Correct me, where I am getting wrong.

Comment: The order in which function arguments are evaluated is not specified.

Comment: Try `int result1 = fun(x-1); int result2 = fun(x+1); return max(result1, result2);`

Comment: I don't get it for what you are asking.

Comment: The order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated is implementation-defined; some compilers (apparently including yours) will evaluate them right-to-left rather than left-to-right.  If you want to force a particular evaluation ordering, you can make your recursive calls separately and store their results into local variables, and then pass those local variables in to max() afterwards.

Comment: as a basic example, your example is far too complicated. Try something simpler, as `void countdown(int i) { if (i == 0) return; std::cout << i; countdown(i-1);}`. Then try to see what happens when you swap the order of the lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified.

When writing `max(fun(x-1),fun(x+1));` the compiler is free to choose to evaluate `fun(x+1)` first.

Comment: So, if according to you compiler is free to choose which argument should be evaluated. Then it means it will give different output if i will run it one more time.

Comment: @t.g no it just means that you have no guarantee which is first. A compiler could choose to always evaluate the first argument while another one might choose to start with the second

Comment: it means you should avoid this kind of code (that has unspecified behaviour).

Comment: ok, I just get it. That the code specified by me has undefined behavior. Moreover, the order of evaluation is compiler dependent. Thnks.